# Heavier than poly transparent coat for vintage door

Tags: painting, staining, polyurethane, shellac

I got this door at a local vintage shop and stripped (for the most part) many coats of paint. I first used `StripKleen`, then `Dumond SmartStrip`, then sanded. There is a little more removal to do (another round of sanding maybe) but here is what it looks now:

[image]

The objective is to achieve a oil-based stained finish (light oak stain, so that original wood grain remains plenty visible) and some transparent finish that is preferably thicker/heavier than polyurethane. Like something half the way between poly and epoxy. I am trying to make it roughly looking like it would have 100 years ago.

My questions are:

1. Should I go with something like shellac or lacquer?
2. Since I used StripKlean and SmartStrip, is there a product I can use to clean/neutralize any chemical residue/conditioning of those products before I apply the stain?

Comment: There is a metric _ton_ of finishing info on [woodworking.se], have a look over there, and maybe even ask to have this migrated.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm open to migrating the question there

Comment: Multiple coats of poly will do the job that’s just how they did it 100 years ago and still do it today if you want the deep shine. Be prepared thick coats of poly or any clear finish will magnify any defects or old paint in the crevices in the molding edges of the reliefs.

Comment: They were applying polyurethane 100 years ago, @EdBeal? #TIL...

Comment: Well the 30’s was the modern urethane prior to that it was boiled linseed oil. But varnish for over 100 years.